# Excel Connection manager fails in SSIS 2012

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2012, ssis

I have a 64 bit Machine running the Visual Studio 2012 shell with Sql Server Data Tools.

In SSIS, I can not get Excel Connections to work at all.  Any excel connection i create comes up with the follow output:

```
Error: 0xC020801C at Load Customer Information, Excel Source [15]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Point" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.
Error: 0xC0047017 at Load Customer Information, SSIS.Pipeline: Excel Source failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.
Error: 0xC004700C at Load Customer Information, SSIS.Pipeline: One or more component failed validation.
Error: 0xC0024107 at Load Customer Information: There were errors during task validation.
```

Generally, this means that it is trying to run in a 64 but runtime.  However, VS2012 only comes in a 32 bit version, and the option for "use64BitRuntime" is greyed out with "false" because the software is 32-bit only.  Does anybody else have any IDea why this would be happening?  I have Excel 2013 32 bit installed.

Comment: The same thing happens for me.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2010/2012 comes with 32-bit version only and hence it cannot use ACE OLEDB 64-bit version, which comes with installation of office 2010 64-bit version.

So the solution here would be uninstall 64-bit version office 2010 and install it's 32-bit version. Re-try to add the excel connection manager.

This has resolved my issue and hope for other guys as well.